# Escaping bug in the Blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, character-escaping

The raw HTML is visible - can this be fixed to have it actually be italics?

It renders as

> Not 4-bit but 4 <em>n</em> bit.

It should be

> Not 4-bit but 4*n*-bit.

[image]

Blog link: https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/14/the-overflow-186-do-large-language-models-know-what-theyre-talking-about/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up. This has now been fixed.